# Removing 'RT @name' from tweet in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, twitter

So, I've been writing a twitter client using node.js and Javscript using node-webkit.

And, eventually I've gotten to the point that retweets are passed on in text.

```
RT @somename: status
```

I've tried finding some sort of regular expression to replace `RT @someone:`, in it's entirety with nothing. But I haven't been able to find anything.

I'm not great with, nor do I understand regular expressions so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following.

```
var str = '@foo @bar @baz RT @somename: status',
    res = str.replace(/RT\s*@\S+/g, '');

console.log(res); // => "@foo @bar @baz  status"
```

Regular expression:

```
RT             'RT'
\s*            whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times)
 @             '@'
 \S+           non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)
```

Another option would be just to match up until and include the colon.

```
str.replace(/RT\s*@[^:]*:/g, '');
```

Comment: How would you adapt this to remove RT or a mention? So, if I'm mentioned in a Tweet "Hey @UserName some other text" It'd return "Hey some other text"

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var text = 'RT @somename: status';
newstr = text.replace(/RT @.+?:/g, '');
document.getElementById('textareaFilter').value = newstr;
```

Here's [an example jsFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/vsRC6/)